# Retornar la posición del valor menor de una lista

Tags: python

Ya logre encontrar el valor mínimo de una lista, sea negativo o positivo. Pero al tratar de retornar el induce no he logrado retornarlo.

este es el código el cual tengo, me gustaría tener ayuda y una explicación de como retornar la posición del valor mínimo, no el valor mínimo como esta retornando ahora mismo el algoritmo si no la posición. Muchas gracias!!

```
lista = [5, 8, 10, -50, 60, -150, 80, 7, -4568]

menor = "inicio"

for i in lista:
    if menor == "inicio":
        menor = i
    else:
        menor = i if i < menor else menor
    
print("menor" + lista.index(menor))
```

Comment: Está funcionando correctamente, solo me lanza error en print(int), el cual corriges con `print("menor" + str(lista.index(menor)))`, así como está la salida es `8`, el cual corresponde al índice de `-4568`

Comment: Muchas gracias, si lo logre solucionar correctamente, no lo concadene con "+" sino que con ","

Comment: Te planteo un escenario: si el numero mas chico existe más de una vez en la lista, el método index te devolverá el indice de la primera ocurrencia del numero. Por ejemplo, teniendo la lista `[1, 1, 2, 3]`, `lista.index(menor)` devolverá 0, que es el indice del primer 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = [5, 8, 10, -50, 60, -150, 80, 7, -4568]
```

El valor mínimo de una lista se puede obtener de una forma simple de la siguiente manera:

```
min(lista)
>> -4568
```

Para obtener el índice de un elemento de una lista, basta con llamar a index, es decir:

```
lista.index(min(lista))
>> 8
```

Espero que te sirva, si necesitas hacerlo explícitamente recorriendo todos los valores de la lista, una forma similar a la que planteas es la siguiente:

```
menor_value, menor_index = 'inicio', 0
for index, value in enumerate(lista):
    if menor_value == 'inicio':
        menor_value = value 
        menor_index = index
    else:
        if value < menor_value:
             menor_value = value 
             menor_index = index
```

Así, tendrías el menor valor en la variable "menor_value" y su índice en la variable "menor_index".